# C++ Create objects in a try bloc then store them in a std::array

Tags: c++, c++11, try-catch, stdarray

I have a `Player` object which can throw an exception inside its constructor, so in my main function I'm creating 2 `Player` objects inside a try block.
I want to store these 2 `Player`s in a `std::array` like that:

```
try
{
  Player p1(10, 10, ikazuchi);
  Player p2(70, 10, hibiki);
  std::array<Player, 2> players = {p1, p2};
}
```

The problem is that I wouldn't be able to use the array outside of the try block, and I heard that placing all the `main` code inside a try block is often a bad idea.

I can't declare my `std::array` after the try block because `p1` and `p2` no longer exist there.

I can solve the problem with a `std::vector`, but I have read that it was better to use a `std::array` when I know the size of the array during the compilation.

I could create a default constructor to create my objects then fill them inside the try block, but it seems to be more proper to create everything in the constructor.

What would be the best practice for that?

Comment: What error are you trying to catch?

Comment: Wait can you reexplain or reword why you don't declare your array outside of the try block?  because you can declare it outside of the try block, and store your players in it inside of the try block...

Comment: Is `Player` noexcept movable ?

Comment: Put the whole of `main` in a `try` block. It is not bad practice (I would recommend it). But the point is that your `std::array` is unusable if you can not create both your players. So it should go out of scope if it can't be initialized.

Comment: @TatsuyukiIshi I throw exception when I'm trying to load the textures for the player but the function return NULL.

Comment: @Eddge I didn't have a default constructor, but thinking about it, it's maybe better to make one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get around issues like this using dynamic allocation or something like `boost::optional<std::array<Player, 2>>`, but the real question is: should you? That is, assume one of the player objects fails to construct and throws an exception. What will you do with the `players` array after that? It's not in a legal state, or at least not in the state you'd expect it to be if no exception was thrown.

There is no problem with having the scope of a `try` be large. It should cover everything where an exception will prevent you from progressing. If you don't like physically having a lot of source code there, move the code into a function. This might be a good idea anyway: one function which assumes all goes well, and another one whose chief responsibility is to handle errors.

And if you have meaningful ways of continuing to use `players` when the objects inside are in an invalid state (constructor threw), then you can just create the array with objects in that state in the first place (outside the `try` block), and just assign them inside the `try`.

The question states you don't want to provide an unneeded default constructor, but I claim that either `player` belongs inside the `try`, or `Player` needs a default constructor (or an equivalent way of expressing "not initialised properly).

Comment: Isn't it a problem if the try block cover my whole code ? Since my Player objects will be used in my event loop... Is it better to don't catch the exception ?

Comment: @Xwilarg You can't think in terms of sweeping rules like "whole code in `try` is bad." Those aren't dogmas. You have to understand them, and understand your code. If your code cannot function without the objects, simply catch & log any exceptions in creating them, and then exit gracefully.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like below.

```
int main() {
  std::array<int, 2> array;
  try {
    array[0]=1;
    array[1]=1;
  } catch (...) {
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Use `Player` instead of `int`;

Comment: I tried to do it but I have the following error since it's in the try bloc: use of deleted function ‘std::array<Player, 2ul>::array()’

Comment: @Xwilarg if you want to use p1 and p2 outside try block then you need to use pointer of Player instead of object of Player.

Comment: @ManthanTilva not necessarily, using when you make an assignment as you did it will make a copy of it in the array.

Comment: The question implies `Player` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: The question implies he didnt make one, that doesn't mean there isn't one unless he implicitly marked it as deleted or made it private it still has a default constructor, it just doesnt set the values.

Comment: @Eddge Wrong. As soon as you have a user-provided ctor, no deault one is generated.

Comment: @Angew http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563221/is-there-an-implicit-default-constructor-in-c

Comment: @Eddge Yes, exactly. "If you do not define **a constructor**, the compiler will define a default constructor for you." Not "if you do not define a **default** constructor." **Any** user-provided ctor inhibits the default ctor. [See also here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0e2c1997fcdd1d1b)

Comment: @Angew just tested it myself inside a test case, you are correct, I could have sworn it was the opposite.

Comment: @Eddge Think about the logic of it. If there's a user-defined ctor, it probably means the class has invariants to maintain. The default ctor would most likely not establish such invariants and thus be wrong. Since C++11, you can request the default ctor using `X() = default;` even if you provide other ctors, if the deafult behaviour is fine for you.

Comment: @Eddge How to test this? Can you share your test case?

Comment: @ManthanTilva I linked to a test case in my earlier comment ("See also here")

Comment: @Angew indeed, that's why I said it doesn't set anything which made sense to me at the time.  I appreciate you correcting me, and preventing the spread of false information thanks.

Comment: I tried to do that, but then I have problems to access to the elements of my object.

Answer (score 0):

If your players csn be copied/moved and trivially constructed, just create the array and assign into it.

```
std::array<Player, 2> players;
try{
  players[0]=Player(10, 10, ikazuchi);
  players[1]=Player(70, 10, hibiki);
} catch ...
```

alternatively you can do:

```
std::optional<std::array<Player, 2>> players;
try{
  Player p1(10, 10, ikazuchi);
  Player p2(70, 10, hibiki);
  players.emplace(std::array<Player, 2>{{std::move(p1),std::move(p2)}});
} catch ...
```

but you may need to find a non-C++17 version of optional, like boost optional.

Another approach is:

```
auto players = [&]()->std::array<Player, 2>{
  try {
    Player p1(10, 10, ikazuchi);
    Player p2(70, 10, hibiki);
    return {{std::move(p1),std::move(p2)}};
  } catch (some_error){
    throw some_other_error;
  }
}();
```

but thus requires exit either by array or by throw.

Comment: As OP states, `Player` doesn't have a default ctor. The first option won't work.