# default constructor for int

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

In an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/507971/1025391) it's said that

> ints are default-constructed as 0, as if you initialized them with int(). Other primitive types are initialized similarly (e.g., double(), long(), bool(), etc.).

Just while I was explaining this to a colleague of mine I made up the following code, [compiled (gcc-4.3.4) and ran](http://ideone.com/8yB1R), and observed unexpected behavior.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int i(); 
  std::cout << i << std::endl; // output is 1
}
```

Why is the output `1` and not `0` ?

Comment: This is explained in: [Why is it an error to use an empty set of brackets to call a constructor with no arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/why-is-it-an-error-to-use-an-empty-set-of-brackets-to-call-a-constructor-with-no)

Comment: I'm surprised it even compiles, as it looks like you stumbled upon the [most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: Congratulations on discovering [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

Comment: If C++ was on Steam, you'd get an achievement now.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**Most vexing parse** comes into play here. You're actually declaring a function `i`, not an `int` variable. It shouldn't even compile (unless you actually have a function `i` defined somewhere... **do you?**).

To value-initialize the int, you need:

```
int i = int();
```

Comment: Implicit cast to `bool`, I think.

Comment: It must be bug in previous versions of GCC; in 4.7, it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Griwes maybe he defines the function somewhere and is un-aware of it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, yet, on Ideone's GCC 4.3.4, it compiles; same for its 4.5.1 in C++11 mode.

Comment: g++ 4.5.1 gives a warning: `Warnung: Die Adresse von »int i()« wird immer zu »wahr« auswerten`, but compiles it fine.

Comment: Also see source code and output here: http://ideone.com/8yB1R

Comment: @moooeeeep yes, but the important part here is that `i` is not an `int` - see http://ideone.com/f7bEP

Comment: It would be nice to see the assembler (can't compile it myself now)

Comment: @AntonioPérez It would indeed, but VS2005 doesn't accept the code :)

Comment: @AntonioPérez I would not expect the assembly to be of any interest, but rather dumb. The equivalent of `std::cout<<true;`. The (slightly more) interesting part is how the compiler got there. `i` decays to a function pointer that cannot be converted to `void*`, so the only valid overload of `<<` is the one that takes `bool`. Conversion to bool yields false only if the pointer is null, but the address of a function cannot be null, so the compiler optimizes the conversion by injecting `true` directly.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas And continuing: the function is "used" if its address is taken, so the absence of a definition somewhere is undefined behavior.  Typically, however... if the compiler optimizes the "use" out (since it knows that the address is non-null), the code will compile and run; if it doesn't, you'll get an undefined symbol when linking.

Comment: Most ODR violations (including this one) are "undefined behaviour, no diagnostic required".  As James suggests, it would make the optimizer's job considerably harder if it were required to generate an error here.